# membershipgroupid value

Tags: sharepoint

I have two different websites created with the same web template on two different web applications.$

On one, my visitor membershipgroupid = 6
On the other, 7.

How is it possible ?

Thank you by advance

Answer (score 0):

Since different webapps as a rule have different databases they do not share ids for web and site specific objects. if there were 5 records in a table X in database A and 6 records in a table X in database B then after creation of a new record in database A in table X its id would be incremented to 6 and after creation a new record in table X in database B the id of a new record would be incremented to 7.